# Prediction on test data using scikit learn pipeline

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using scikit learn pipeline to build a rf model. Then I compute predictions on train data and test data. Both the data set have different number of rows.

Code:-

```
#Fit pipeline on train data
Y=dataFile['class'].tolist()
pipeline.fit(dataFile,Y)

#Predict on train data
Y_pred=pipeline.predict(dataFile);

#Predict on test data
Yt=dataTest['class'].tolist()
Yt_pred=pipeline.predict(dataTest)

#Print length of prediction and true labels
print("Length Train:"+str(len(Y_pred))+","+str(len(Y)))
print("Length Test:"+str(len(Yt_pred))+","+str(len(Yt)))
```

Output of the code

```
Length Train:20900,20900
Length Test:20900,34321
```

For test data pipeline.predict is not returning correct number of predictions. Rather the number of predictions are same as that in training.

Please let know if anything is wrong here.

Comment: What is `len(dataTest)`?

Comment: It is 34321 same as len(Yt)

Comment: No my predictions are in Yt_pred while true labels are in Yt. The length of Yt is 34321 but the length of Yt_pred is 20900. len(Yt_pred) should be 34321 but it is 20900

Comment: Resolved I made an error in another function that caused the issue